# A semisimple matrix that is not diagonalizable over algebraic closure?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

In [this quetion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767975/textv-is-semisimple-as-a-kx-module-if-and-only-if-a-in-operatornameen), it has been proved that an operator is semisimple iff it's diagonalizable over the algebraic closure of the base field.

However, when the minimal polynomial is not separable, it seems that there's something going wrong. Consider operator on $\mathbb F_2(t)$ to be

$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
&&1&\\
&&&1\\
t&&&\\
&t&&
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Clearly it has minimal polynomial $m(x)=x^2+t$, which is irreducible but not separable on $\mathbb F_2(t)$.

Then by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_operator), $T$ is semisimple since $m(x)$ is a product of irreducible factors. While $T$ only has two linearly independent eigenvectors $(1,0,\sqrt t,0)$ and $(0,1,0,\sqrt t)$ in $\mathbb F_2(\sqrt t)$.

What's wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your definition of semisimple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering the bases, you just have the diagonal sum of two copies of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\t&0\end{bmatrix}$. This has characteristic polynomial $x^2+t$, as you noted, which factorises over the algebraic closure as $(x+\sqrt t)^2$. This has a repeated root, so the matrix is not necessarily diagonalisable.

The result you (mis-)quoted says semisimplicity is the same as the minimal polynomial splitting into *distinct* linear factors over the algebraic closure. In our example the minimal polynomial is the characteristic polynomial, so the matrix is not diagonalisable.

It must therefore yield the Jordan block $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt t&1\\0&\sqrt t\end{bmatrix}$. Taking the basis $u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\\sqrt t\end{bmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1+\sqrt t\end{bmatrix}$ shows that this is indeed the case.

Comment: You now added the link to Wikipedia. The result there is currently also wrong. Either work over a perfect field, or else take distinct _separable_ irreducible polynomials.

Comment: So the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767975/textv-is-semisimple-as-a-kx-module-if-and-only-if-a-in-operatornameen) is generally wrong if the base field is not perfect?

Comment: It would seem that many people overlook this issue, yes. Over an algebraically-closed field, semisimplicity equates to the minimal polynomial having no repeated roots. The minimal polynomial is defined over the base field (see eg. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66916/367470). So semisimplicity equates to the minimal polynomial being a product of distinct separable polynomials.