# What is the name of this theorem in English?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space $E$ over the field $K$ and let $P \in K[x]$. Let $P=QR$ with $Q$ and $R$ relatively prime.

Then

$$Ker[P(f)]= Ker[Q(f)]\oplus Ker[R(f)].$$

In French this is called the "lemme des noyaux" or "théorème de la décomposition des noyaux" which translates to kernel decomposition theorem.

Comment: An answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275186/the-connection-between-decomposition-of-kerf-phi-g-phi-and-the-chinese-re suggests it doesn't have a common English name.

Comment: That is suprising, as it has many powerful applications in the theory of diagonalisation.

Comment: I've discovered the french name when I arrived in France. Before it didn't have a name for me